# Is there any Background service for synchronizing my SQLite data to server in ionic 2?

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I created an ionic 2 application which will save data into SQLite storage for offline mode access. When mobile has internet connection i should be able to sync all SQLite data back to Server.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to add a **Resume Method** in your **app.component.ts** so everytime your App gets started, from Background or new Startup or whatever, it will fire that function. In this function you check if the device has Internet. If Internet is aviable check if all is synched or new Data is aviable. If new Data is aviable then send it to your Server and store it.

You can add a Resume Methode like this:

```
  initializeApp(){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      document.addEventListener('resume', () => { 
        //HERE IS YOUR ONRESUME CODE
        //Get your Storage and check if something has changed
        //Check if Internet is aviable
        //Send Data to your Server
 });
.....................
```